# change click event in function name call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, customdialog

I am trying to customize the default delete confirm popup.I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/invetek/jquery-confirmon/)
 to customize the popup.In plugin,they demonstrated using button onclick.But in my application i am using confirm dialog box inside the javascript function,

Actual sample from plugin

```
           $('#button_2').confirmOn({
                questionText: 'This action cannot be undone, are you sure?',
                textYes: 'Yes, I\'m sure',
                textNo: 'No, I\'m not sure'
            },'click', function(e, confirmed) {
                if(confirmed) $(this).remove();
            });
```

I tried in the below to customize the confirm dialog,

```
    function deleteFollow(url, obj){
         confirmOn({
                questionText: 'This action cannot be undone, are you sure?',
                textYes: 'Yes, I\'m sure',
                textNo: 'No, I\'m not sure'
            }, 'click', function(e, confirmed){

  if(confirmed) 
      ''''''''''''
      ajax post comes here
     ''''''''''''''''
```

The above giving the error in console as "`Uncaught ReferenceError: confirmOn is not defined` ".How to implement or alter the original for my actual function.

Answer (score 1):

your second `confirmOn()` does not have the jQuery prefix:

```
function deleteFollow(url, obj){
     confirmOn({
            //your code
```

should be:

```
function deleteFollow(url, obj){
     $.confirmOn({
            //your code
```

or:

```
function deleteFollow(url, obj){
     $("#foo").confirmOn({
            //your code
```

Comment: Previous issue solved,i am getting this issue now "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'confirmOn' of object function (a,b){
        return new p.fn.init(a,b,c)
        } is not a function " .Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

try your code

```
function deleteFollow(url, obj){
         confirmOn({
                questionText: 'This action cannot be undone, are you sure?',
                textYes: 'Yes, I\'m sure',
                textNo: 'No, I\'m not sure'
            },
```

change to

```
function deleteFollow(url, obj){
         $.confirmOn({
                questionText: 'This action cannot be undone, are you sure?',
                textYes: 'Yes, I\'m sure',
                textNo: 'No, I\'m not sure'
            },
```

Comment: I tried like this,i am getting this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if "